# DD MMM YYYY Date format

Tags: sharepoint-online

Is there any region/Locale setting in SharePoint Online where the date formats to:
DD MMM YYYY?

The closest I have gotten to is DD MM YYYY, but would like the date to be for example: 26 jul 2020.

Comment: The 21 in 21 26 jul 2020 is at 21 o'clock？

Comment: 21 came by mistake, it should be like this: 26-JUL-2020

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sharepoint global time format depends on the region setting. If there is no country using this format to display time, then the global time format cannot be modified to that.

If you want to get this format of time in some places,code for your reference:

```
new Date().format("dd MMM yyyy");
```

Test result:
[image]